# Best practice constructor with parameters in inherited classes

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have following easy class design, where myObject is importing for BaseClass.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(myObject parameter)
    {
        // ...
    }   
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{

}
```

My problem is now, that I want to make my program extensible by inheriting from public BaseClass. So you could create a constructor

```
public ChildClass() :base(new myObject()){...}
```

which will lead to failures. Is there a possibilty to prevent inherited classes with own constructors? I actually would like to avoid constructors for ChildClass at all. Is this possible? Then I could use a factory and provide an Initialize method. Or is this something impossible, where I simply must be aware of and check in my code=

Comment: Constructors aren't inherited, and a class _must_ have a constructor.  If you don't define any constructors, a parameterless constructor is implied.  Exactly what situations are you trying to avoid?

Comment: There's nothing you can do to prevent constructors from being written.  You can of course agree to use a Factory pattern and make only private constructors and implement some IInitializable interface or something.

Comment: Ok, I now they must have a constructor, but I would like to allow only one constructor with certain parameters. Like struct did not allow parameterless constructors

Comment: If your design aim is to support factory pattern, why not consider a dependency injection container (such as Autofac, Unity or Ninject) to construct your objects.  Setup correctly, these will allow the construction of objects through a container (much like a factory) even if the types rely on non-default constructors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Classes are completely responsible for their own constructors.  They aren't inherited, and every class *must* have a constructor.  So no, there's nothing you can do to "control" what constructors a base class can or can't have.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Then I guess, I will check the class for forbidden constructors and throw an error.

Comment: What would make a constructor "forbidden"?  Just curious what situations you're trying to avoid.

Comment: @Matt if you can't trust the invokers of your code, something has gone wrong.  Seems like you're trying to solve a problem that shouldn't exist.

Comment: @DavidL May be, you're right. I think I should rethink this part of the solution and read some general best practices in extensibilty of programs